# Does GnuCash have an easy way to track subsidiaries of companies within one account?

Tags: gnucash

So is there a way to track expenses related to different companies from within the same gnucash file?

For example we have two companies that are subsidiaries of another company. We are constantly transfering money back and forth, so would be nice if I could do it all in one transaction instead of having to show deposit in one file and then open seperate file for other company and show the withdrawl.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but having gone to the trouble of separating the entities, are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up specific expense accounts and income accounts within the parent company's chart of accounts that relate only to one subsidiary company.  Ditto for the other subsidiary.  That way, you treat each subsidiary as a "Profit Centre" within the parent company.

But doing that is probably not consistent with the reason for setting up subsidiary companies in the first place.

If there was a valid reason for setting the subsidiary up as a company in its own right, then it deserves to have its own set of books.  Each subsidiary company will make a profit or loss, and will have assets and liabilities.  You can't track all of that, and know the performance of the company, without a proper accounting system for the company.